# Send SMS Message using PHP

Tags: php, curl, sms-gateway

I have developed  a system which will send SMS to the customer after making insert to the database 
but the system which I worked on is public ie. when my client asked me to buy the system he must insert his SMS API configuration to send a message to his customers 
when I searched on the internet I found that every API have a differnt way to send SMS message 
I have account in click tell API but when I send message by curl there is nothing happen 
the code is

```
$url = 'https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?' . http_build_query(
    [
      'apiKey' =>  'oGjnzDdSRhqdhhgnjFj3ZmzYA==',
   //   'api_secret' => '4c98619ffb9af51585',
      'to' => '94233698311783',

      'content' => 'Hello from Netcom'
    ]
);
echo($url);echo('<br/>');
echo'https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=oGkmzDdSRgekvjFjaZnzYA==&to=905373545631&content=Test+message+text"';
$ch = curl_init($url);
echo($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

Where my code is wrong and what is the way to send SMS dynamically depending on the client's API info

Comment: the information which I provided not correct

Comment: Please correct the title of your question

Comment: do not share your API keys to public

Comment: ...and add some punctuation to your text. Your question is also quite unclear. What exactly is it you're having issues with? What's the response from the call? Error messages?

Comment: there is no any error  only blank page

Comment: @M.Bwe check my answer below hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

For quick fix and testing add this in your curl request and check response.(Because url is `https`)

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

But it is recomonded to downloading a CA root certificate bundle at the curl website and saving it on your server which protect your site

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of Clickatell, but Aws SNS is quite simple,

$payload = array(

```
                'Message' => $message,
                'PhoneNumber' => $mobile,
                'MessageAttributes' => $msgAttributes
            );

$result = $sns->publish($payload);
```

Comment: How does this help the OP making calls to Click tell?